# Integral of Legendre's function

Tags: integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, legendre-polynomials

Is there any formula for computing the following integral $$\int_a^1(P^m_l)^2(x)\,dx \, ,\text{with} -1<a<1$$
where $P^m_l$ is the associated Legendre's function (of the first kind) of order $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and of degree $l=-0.5+it$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/366081

Comment: with that $a$ in there, you are asking for the indefinite integral.

Comment: the variable $a$ belongs to $(-1;1)$.